# Handling PHP Array post values and merging - PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I know this won't take much time for experts here. But still please help me out

My Array output is like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 37 [2] => 1035 ) 1
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 37 [2] => 1035 ) mystatusmessage1

Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 37 [2] => 2925 ) 2
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 37 [2] => 2925 ) mystatusmessage2
```

What I would like to get it is in a single string value like this so that I can insert into database.

```
1,37,1035,1,mystatusmessage1
4,37,2925,2,mystatusmessage2
```

How can I achieve that. I'm trying to do with foreach but still I'm not able to do it.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Try `implode()` with a comma as the [http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: yes i did that. but please check my array value above. i have to merge array values with the existing one. that i am not able to do. please can u help me

Comment: Where do you get the `1` and `mystatusmessage1` outside the array from? Those are from `$_POST` is that right?

Answer (score 0):

use implode function to make string from array for example

if you have array like Array('a','b','c');

```
  implode(',',array('a','b','c') )
```

will return a,b,c as string

here first argument is your glue by which you want to join string

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
// Original array
$array  =   array(0 => 1, 1 => 37, 2 => 1035);
// $_POST array
$_POST  =   array(1,'mystatusmessage1');
// Jump to the end of array
end($array);
// Merge the post with original array
$newArr =   array_merge($array,$_POST);
// Impode
echo implode(",",$newArr);
```

Repeat with other array.